# Msbuild error in command line,Error MSB4067

Tags: git, msbuild

Error MSB4067 ,when trying to build my project from command line console, I got this error

[image: <ItemDefinitionGroup> unrecognized]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your .Net Framework v4.0, Run this with Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt

Answer (score 2):

Your Visual Studio Command prompt is going to invoke VCVARS32.BAT and apply settings to consume v2.0 MsBuild.

From the command line use the path to v4:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

Edit: Plus if you want the latest build tools, MsBuild is no longer included in .NET and now a part of Visual Studio and [available as a separate download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760).

Note that if you go with MsBuild 12 the path would be under %ProgramFiles%\MsBuild.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this: I had a WPFCustomControlLibrary. And it gives me the same error. I opened csproj file in notepad and deleted  Import tag with the whole attributes.